# cannot get file extension with NodeJS and mime package

Tags: node.js, mime-types, mime

I try to get a file extension from a 'video/avi' mimetype.

I'm using the mime package on NodeJs. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime).

```
var mime = require('mime');
mime.extension('video/mp4'); // return mp4
mime.extension('video/avi'); // doesn't work.
```

When i'm using mime.extension() with 'video/avi' mimetype as param, undefined is returned.

What is the solution ?

**I don't want split file name to get extension.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

video/avi is missing in mime types. you can define if you want.

```
mime.define({
    'video/avi': ['avi']
});

mime.extension('video/avi'); // return avi
```

Answer (score 2):

In Version 2,

**extension()** renamed to **getExtension()**